# How to add a JRE 1.8 into Eclipse Installer JRE?

Tags: spring, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying deploy my Spring Boot application to Elastic Beanstalk.

The problem that I am facing right now is, my application is developed with Tomcat 9, Java 13 and Project Facet 4.0.

So when I deployed to a AWS environment, I kept getting error. After researching, I found out AWS only support Tomcat 8, Java 8 and Project Facet 3.0.

I managed to change Project Facet 4.0 to 3.0.

But I can't add Java 8 to the project.

I downloaded the JDK 8 from Oracle, and tried open jdk-8u251-macosx-x64.dmg and run JDK 8 Update 251.pkg.

The system keeps giving me error that: **"JDK 8 Update 251.pkg" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software. This software needs to be updated.**

Anyone know how to fix this problem so that I can run JRE 8 on eclipse?

Here is picture the problem that I have when I deploy the app to AWS.
[An internal error occurred during: Updating AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5hza.png)

Here is the thread that I tried to follow but without success:
https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-eclipse/issues/149.

Comment: Try an equivalent OpenJDK build from https://adoptopenjdk.net/ or Amazon's own Corretto builds at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html .

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate where exactly are you seeing the error? While running the JDK package or while configuration the JDK within Eclipse?

Nevertheless, I suppose your main requirement is to get your Eclipse to use Java 8.

It can be done in multiple ways.

1. Usually you can change Java compiler level to 1.8 from Project Settings even if you're using Java 13.
2. If you're using Maven, you can specify compiler source and target to Java 1.8

   ```
   <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
   ```
3. Alternatively, you can download the JDK 8 zip instead of installer, unzip to any location and use that in Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs. Be sure to mark that one as default JRE.

[image: Installed JREs]

Comment: I tried to follow your step but problem still remain. I have updated the question, hope that it will more clear.

Comment: Please provide some screen shots, especially the installed JREs section from your Eclipse workspace.

General > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs

Comment: Updated answer with image to specify JDK 8